# 2013 Mitsubishi lancer and the battery terminal snapped

Tags: battery

Im looking for a replacement but the only part that pops up is a 2003-2006 lancer battery terminal, my question is would this be a sufficient replacement?? It does look the same

Comment: Have you checked with a dealer? Where does this "pop up"?

Comment: There are not really that many kinds of battery terminals, they're pretty standardized. You may be better off just [buying a replacement cable](https://www.autozone.com/batteries-starting-and-charging/battery-cable), it's not that much more money, and connecting a new terminal to an existing cable can be unreliable.